# React-Flux not showing array of objects from sockets

Tags: javascript, socket.io, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm still trying to render data from sockets but something is wrong with my code I really don't know what. If I put json data diractly into store items are rendered good. But If data are received from the sockets there is some problem with map function inside List.js.
I've also repository for it: [github](https://github.com/makromat/RCT-FLX)

**APP**

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <ListContainer />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**ListContainer**

```
var ListContainer = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    list: React.PropTypes.array,
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      list: todoStore.getList()
    }
  },
    componentWillMount: function componentWillMount() {
        this.socket = io('www.example.com');
        this.socket.on('tables', this.handleAddItem);
    },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    todoStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    todoStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },
  handleAddItem: function(newItem) {
      console.log("handleAddItem called");
    todoActions.addItem(newItem);
  },
  handleRemoveItem: function(index) {
    todoActions.removeItem(index);
  },
  _onChange: function() {
    this.setState({
      list: todoStore.getList()
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3" },
        React.createElement(List, { items: this.state.list, remove: this.handleRemoveItem })
      )
    )
  }
});
```

**Actions**

```
var todoActions = {
  addItem: function(item) {
      console.log("Action called");
    AppDispatcher.handleAction({
      actionType: appConstants.ADD_ITEM,
      data: item
    });
  },
  removeItem: function(index) {
    AppDispatcher.handleAction({
      actionType: appConstants.REMOVE_ITEM,
      data: index
    });
  }
};
```

**AppDispatcher**

```
AppDispatcher.handleAction = function(action) {
  this.dispatch({
    source: 'VIEW_ACTION',
    action: action
  });
};
```

**todoStore**

```
var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

var _store = {
  list: []
};
var addItem = function(item) {
   console.log("push to store called");
  _store.list.push(item);
};
var removeItem = function(index) {
  _store.list.splice(index, 1);
};
var todoStore = objectAssign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  addChangeListener: function(cb) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, cb);
  },
  removeChangeListener: function(cb) {
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, cb);
  },
  getList: function() {
    return _store.list;
  }
});
AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
  var action = payload.action;
  switch(action.actionType) {
    case appConstants.ADD_ITEM:
      addItem(action.data);
      console.log("Dispacher called");
      todoStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
      break;
    case appConstants.REMOVE_ITEM:
      removeItem(action.data);
      todoStore.emit(CHANGE_EVENT);
      break;
    default:
      return true;
  }
});
```

**List**

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item, index) {
      return (
        <li key={index} className="list-group-item">
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
          </span>
          <span>
           {console.log(item.title)} 
          </span>
        </li>
      )
    }.bind(this));
    return (
      <ul>
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    )
  }
});
```

I got error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, title, name, createdAt, updatedAt}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of List

If I receive one object in socket it works pretty good. But I wanted to render multiple objects from array... How can I do that ?
Thanks for any help!

**MAYBE SOLUTION**
It works with this code but is it good solution ?

```
handleAddItem: function(newItem) {

  for(var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++){
      todoActions.addItem(newItem[i]);
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one problem.

```js
var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item, index) {
      console.log(item);
      return (
        <li key={index} className="list-group-item">
          <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
          </span>
          <span>
           {item.name}{item.title}
          </span>
        </li>
      )
    }, this);
    return (
      <ul>
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    )
  }
});
```

```js
[
  {
    "comment": "",
    "snip": "<i class=\"fa fa-camera-retro\"></i>"
  },
  {
    "comment": "button with image lines up wrong without this",
    "snip": "* { outline: none; }\n"
  },
  {
    "comment": "",
    "snip": ".TreeButtonImg {\n\tpadding: 0px;\n\tvertical-align: top;\n}"
  }
]
```

```js
class SnipListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { super(); }
  snipClickHandler = (buttonid) => { Actions.selectSnipItem(this.props.snippet, buttonid); }
  render() {
    let SnipSpanSty = {width: 'calc(70% - 142px)'};
    SnipSpanSty.color = (this.props.index === this.props.selectedKey) ? '#b58900' : '#afac87';
    return (
      <div id='SnipDivSty' onclick={this.snipClickHandler} className="FlexBox" style={SnipDivSty}>
        <div id='SelectSnipDivSty' style={SelectSnipDivSty}>
          <JButton btn={selectSnipBtn} parentClickHandler={this.snipClickHandler} />
        </div>
        <span id='SnipSpanSty' style={SnipSpanSty}>{this.props.snippet.snip}</span>
        <JButton btn={SnipBtn} parentClickHandler={this.snipClickHandler} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

let _snipDataMap = function(snip, index) {
  return (
    <li id='SnipsDivLiSty' key={index} style={SnipsDivLiSty}>
      <SnipListItem snippet={snip} index={index} selectedKey={this.props.selectedKey} />
    </li>
  );
}

export default class SnipsView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let list = this.props.data.map(_snipDataMap, this)
    return (
      <div id='SnipsDivSty' style={SnipsDivSty}>
        <ul id='SnipsDivUlSty' style={SnipsDivUlSty}>
          {list}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but only if I have one object in sockets but If I use array of objects it does not. Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that the array of objects are somehow not in the expected format.

Comment: Should look like [{name: 'one', title: 'onet'},{name: 'two', title: 'twot'}]

Comment: yes exactly like I already have ... strange. Maybe I will back to backbonejs rather :D... If I do like     todoActions.addItem(newItems[0]); it is working well. But there is only one object rendered sure...

Comment: I added an example from a working app. The whole thing is at https://github.com/calitek/Clippets.

Comment: Please take a look now. It works but I don't know whether is this solution good idea. I'm doing **for loop** for every item in array and then push each one into store. Is it good idea? What do you think?